# Scale/shrink a number based on frame rate

Tags: c++, math, logic, unreal-engine4

Say i have the number 32 at 60 frame rate

- based on the frame rate how do i calculate and get the number if frame rate goes to 20 or 70?

Comment: It is not really clear what you want to do. Could you please clarify what your expected output for a given input is. In addition to that, StackOverflow is not a code writing service. So you should show what you tried to calculate that yourself, and explain for which cases your approach does not work.

Comment: This question should include more details and clarify the problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not entirely sure what you are trying to achieve here --

Given your example wherein X is equal to 32 when the FPS is 60 you could calculate the value of X when the FPS is 1 `FPS(32) / X(60)` this gives you a value of `0.53` with this value calculated you could declare a constant float that you can then use to calculate the value of X based on the FPS.

- At 20 FPS the value of x would be 10.6 (0.53 * 20)
- At 70 FPS the value of x would be 37.3 (0.53 * 70)

Comment: Exactly. thanks for clear explanation.

Comment: More than welcome.